# Preventing Variable Population

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

I need to append the command below to a txt file. The problem is that it echoes the contents of the variables into the file and not the command itself. I have tried to escape the variables unsuccessfully.

```
echo set dates='%date:~7,2%' - '%date:~4,2%' - '%date:~10,4%' > D.bat
```

Result in D.bat:

```
set dates='10' - '11' - '2016'
```

Any help would be dearly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

If you put your first command into a batch file, and then double up percentages, it will echo them out to `D.bat` with a single percentage, and not populate the variables:

Batch file `A.bat`:

```
echo set dates='%%date:~7,2%%' - '%%date:~4,2%%' - '%%date:~10,4%%' > D.bat
```

After you run `A.bat`, `D.bat` will contain:

```
set dates='%date:~7,2%' - '%date:~4,2%' - '%date:~10,4%'
```

And when you run `D.bat`, the output will have the variables populated.